# Returning a bluebird promise after sequilize db operation

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, bluebird

I got a function that should delete a DB row. The function gets the id of the row that should be deleted. Also the function should return the deleted row to perform some text outputs.

```
    deleteProcess(processToDeleteId: any): Promise<ProcessInstance> {
    let deletedProcess;
    let value;

    for (let key in processToDeleteId) {
        if (processToDeleteId.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            value = processToDeleteId[key];
        }
    }

    this.sequelize.query("select * from Processes where processId = ?",
        { replacements: [value], type: this.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then(function (processes) {
            for (let item in processes) {
                if (processes.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                    deletedProcess = processes[item];
                    console.log(deletedProcess);
                }
            }

        })
        .delay(20);

    let that = this;
    return new Promise<ProcessInstance>(
        (function (resolve, reject) {
            that.sequelize.query("delete from Processes where processId = ?",
                { replacements: [value], type: that.sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE })
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('Deleted successfully');
                    return deletedProcess;
                })
            reject(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
    )
};
```

The issue is the function works well in therms of deleting the item, also it loads the row that is deleted, but doesn't returns the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call resolve, which you need to if you want to populate a promise created through the promise constructor. That said, I don't believe you need the promise constructor here.

Does it work if you do this?

```
    return that.sequelize.query("delete from Processes where processId = ?",
        { replacements: [value], type: that.sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE })
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Deleted successfully');
            return deletedProcess;
        })
        .catch(console.log)
```

By the way, you don't need to do `let that = this;` if you use an [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)